# Unmarshalling Complex Json

Tags: json, go, reddit

I just recently started working with apis and http requests and I'm trying to build an application that uses the Reddit API to pull posts on a specific subreddit.

This is the the page with json and search parameters that I'm practicing on:
https://www.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads.json?limit=1

Looking at the standard library of the JSON module for Golang, I still don't understand how to use json.Unmarshal for this complex JSON. From what I gather, I have to define a struct that resembles the JSON structure to actually hold the data

I posted the link into this website to get a feel for what the JSON is actually strucutred like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Right now the main thing I'm after is the title which is under Data->Children->Data->Title. If I want to unmarshal the JSON into an object, do I define a nested struct object? Or is there a simpler way to do this so that I don't have to figure out all the attributes of the JSON and define them myself??

Any help that can get me on the right track is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to define fields you don't need in your struct. Unmarshal will only decode the values that are present in your struct. But with nested JSONs you unfortunately have to define all the parent fields also (unlike in xml package in which you can define paths in tags). So your struct could look like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    Data struct {
        Children []struct {
            Data struct {
                Title string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See here for a working example: https://play.golang.org/p/UeUYfWBONL

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very simple and concise. I don't know much about XML either, but I think I'll take a look at it to see how it differs from JSON.

Comment: The difference is that in xml package if you want to decode nested values you can put paths in tags like this: `type Foo struct { Title string 'xml:"data>children>data>title"'}` No idea why it's not possible in json package as it's really handy, having to only define a single struct (instead of 4 in this case). Otherwise the package is really similiar

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the JSON you are trying to unmarshal is over complex, so your struct has to be complex, but that's the way it goes.

There are a few tools that generate struct definitions from a JSON, and that saves a ton of work. Using the JSON you posted and [such an online tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), I generated the following struct:

```
package main

type MyJsonName struct {
    Data struct {
        After    string      `json:"after"`
        Before   interface{} `json:"before"`
        Children []struct {
            Data struct {
                ApprovedBy          interface{}   `json:"approved_by"`
                Archived            bool          `json:"archived"`
                Author              string        `json:"author"`
                AuthorFlairCSSClass string        `json:"author_flair_css_class"`
                AuthorFlairText     interface{}   `json:"author_flair_text"`
                BannedBy            interface{}   `json:"banned_by"`
                Clicked             bool          `json:"clicked"`
                ContestMode         bool          `json:"contest_mode"`
                Created             int           `json:"created"`
                CreatedUtc          int           `json:"created_utc"`
                Distinguished       string        `json:"distinguished"`
                Domain              string        `json:"domain"`
                Downs               int           `json:"downs"`
                Edited              bool          `json:"edited"`
                Gilded              int           `json:"gilded"`
                Hidden              bool          `json:"hidden"`
                HideScore           bool          `json:"hide_score"`
                ID                  string        `json:"id"`
                IsSelf              bool          `json:"is_self"`
                Likes               interface{}   `json:"likes"`
                LinkFlairCSSClass   string        `json:"link_flair_css_class"`
                LinkFlairText       string        `json:"link_flair_text"`
                Locked              bool          `json:"locked"`
                Media               interface{}   `json:"media"`
                MediaEmbed          struct{}      `json:"media_embed"`
                ModReports          []interface{} `json:"mod_reports"`
                Name                string        `json:"name"`
                NumComments         int           `json:"num_comments"`
                NumReports          interface{}   `json:"num_reports"`
                Over18              bool          `json:"over_18"`
                Permalink           string        `json:"permalink"`
                Quarantine          bool          `json:"quarantine"`
                RemovalReason       interface{}   `json:"removal_reason"`
                ReportReasons       interface{}   `json:"report_reasons"`
                Saved               bool          `json:"saved"`
                Score               int           `json:"score"`
                SecureMedia         interface{}   `json:"secure_media"`
                SecureMediaEmbed    struct{}      `json:"secure_media_embed"`
                Selftext            string        `json:"selftext"`
                SelftextHTML        string        `json:"selftext_html"`
                Stickied            bool          `json:"stickied"`
                Subreddit           string        `json:"subreddit"`
                SubredditID         string        `json:"subreddit_id"`
                SuggestedSort       interface{}   `json:"suggested_sort"`
                Thumbnail           string        `json:"thumbnail"`
                Title               string        `json:"title"`
                Ups                 int           `json:"ups"`
                URL                 string        `json:"url"`
                UserReports         []interface{} `json:"user_reports"`
                Visited             bool          `json:"visited"`
            } `json:"data"`
            Kind string `json:"kind"`
        } `json:"children"`
        Modhash string `json:"modhash"`
    } `json:"data"`
    Kind string `json:"kind"`
}
```

Usually, the output of these tools still needs to manual tweaking to work properly. for example:

```
MediaEmbed          struct{}      `json:"media_embed"`
```

I'm pretty sure that's not what's needed here. But it does go a long way in showing the basic idea and figuring out most of the stuff correctly. There are other similar tools you can try.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The tool seems very useful and will certainly help in the future working with JSON. Thanks again.